# Batch file call command not finishing prior to next command

Tags: batch-file, dir, network-drive

I'm running a batch file

```
cd desktop

net use z: \\NETWORKCOMPUTER1-PC\i
z:

cd movies
dir > c:movies.txt
cd ..\shows
dir > c:shows.txt
cd ..\anime
dir > c:anime.txt

net use z: /delete
```

At the end it gives this message:

```
"There are open files and/or incomplete directory searches pending on the connection to z:.

Is it OK to continue disconnecting and force them closed? (Y/N) [N]:"
```

At which time I select 'N' and all the text files are created correctly.

How do I make it not delete the network connection until it's done creating the last text file?

**Resolved** - Needed to switch back to c: before deleting the z: network connection.

Comment: May I ask why the hell you're prefixing each and every command with `call`?

Comment: Because CALL is supposed to wait for a command to finish before moving to the next line of the batch file. If I don't preface with call, then the first directory listing doesn't even finish before it moves to the next. For this reason I just preface every line in a batch file that I wish to be executed sequentially with a call.

Comment: No, that's not what CALL does.  START /WAIT does that, but you don't need it.  Your impression that the first directory listing doesn't even finish before it moves to the next is wrong.  Show us your entire output, preferably using a special test directory structure which contains only a few files.

Comment: Sorry. I must have gotten confused reading some other posts and the documentation. I removed the call commands the directory listings complete. They didn't earlier but probably due to some other syntactical error I've since rectified. So all that remains is the original issue in my question.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're setting `z:` as the current drive near the top of your script.

So, to avoid the message, right before you attempt to delete the `z:` mapping set the current drive to `c:` (or whatever other drive you wish).

For example, something like this:

```
NET USE Z: \\ComputerName\FolderShare
Z:

REM Do some stuff here with files/folders on Z:

REM Change current drive to C: before removing the network drive.
C:

NET USE Z: /DELETE
```

Comment: That fixed it. I changed back to c: at the end. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Even better: `pushd \\computer\share` and `popd` at the end. No need for `Z:` to still be free, for example.

Comment: Could you elaborate with a script in the answer I'm still not getting it after reading this.  Thanks.

Comment: @Lightsout I added a small sample script.